# Servlet UnavailableException:No class in holder while starting jetty

Tags: jetty

Can anyone tell me what causes this exception while jetty server is starting. I am using jetty 9.2.2

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: No class in holder

The web.xml contains

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.test.api.TestApiApplication</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.test.api.TestApiApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The TestApiApplication.java extends Application

```
public class TestApiApplication extends Application {

 public TestApiApplication() {
 }

@Override
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    s.add(TestResource.class);
    return s;
 } 
}
```

The drilled down version of my pom.xml is:

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.11</jersey.version>
    <spring.framework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.0</jaxrs.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: No class in holder
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at yjava.servlet.container.jetty.JettyDaemon.start(JettyDaemon.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:177)
```

Comment: What does `yjava.servlet.container.jetty.JettyDaemon.start` do?

Answer (score 2):

Would need to know how Jetty is started in your `yjava.servlet.container.jetty.JettyDaemon` to answer with any more depth.

If you want auto-wiring of Jersey, using Servlet 3.0 technique as outlined by [`org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.html), then that `JettyDaemon` class will have to enable the various annotation scanning configurations for Jetty.

For starters, your web.xml declaration is bad.

Yours (reformatted to be readable)

```xml
<web-app version="3.0" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

That XML is invalid, the `web-app` element isn't closed, and you are missing some of the required attributes.

Correct for Servlet 3.0:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

But your environment is Servlet 3.1, per your choice of Jetty 9 and the use of servlet-api 3.1.0 in your pom.xml, so that declaration would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     metadata-complete="false"
     version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I updated the name space section in web.xml. But it turns out that I had to define the <servlet-name> and <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer<servlet-class>. But As per jersey spec I dont need to do this http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-documentation/2.11/jersey-documentation-2.11-user-guide.pdf (4.7.2. Servlet 3.x Container)

Comment: @Sharadr your JettyDaemon doesn't have its environment and/or configurations setup properly for annotation scanning and SCI use.

Comment: can you please let me know why do you think that my JettyDaemon isn't property setup ?

Comment: The fact that Jersey's SCI wasn't executed, tells me that.  Be sure you set your WebAppContext configurations to support annotations - see example project at https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.1/blob/master/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EmbedMe.java

Answer (score 1):

Changing the web.xml as below fixed my problem. I had to specify servlet-name and servlet-class. I tried the other way as described in [Jersey 2.11 spec](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-documentation/2.11/jersey-documentation-2.11-user-guide.pdf).
I followed the steps in 4.7.1. Servlet 2.x Container =>Example 4.9. Hooking up Jersey as a Servlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
      metadata-complete="false" version="3.1">   

      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>TestApp</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.api.TestApiApplication</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the pom.xml's content of servlet to `jersey-container-servlet`.